Prevent clang-format breaking on << operator
I am trying to create a .clang-format file using this website: https://clang-format-configurator.site/ (version set to 17.0.6)
but in this code snippet, the std::cout gets formatted onto the next line when it should all just stay onto the same line.
// Before formatting
const auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
const float deltaTime = static_cast<float>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(currentTime - previousTime).count()) / 1000000.0f;
previousTime = currentTime;

std::cout << "MyClass::Run " << sPassedTime << "s - (" << deltaTime << ")" << "\n";

// After formatting
const auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
const float deltaTime = static_cast<float>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(currentTime - previousTime).count()) / 1000000.0f;
previousTime = currentTime;

std::cout << "MyClass::Run " << sPassedTime << "s - (" << deltaTime << ")"
          << "\n"; // <-- format changed, but shouldn't

I have these options set as following:

AlignOperands: Align
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
ColumnLimit: 160

i only want the binary operators to wrap when the characters surpass the column limit, but the line ondeltaTime is much longer (barely within 160) and does not get wrapped. What options do i need to change to prevent it from formatting? Using the website it does break on version 17 but not on version 18.
---
Language: Cpp
Standard: c++17
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: Align
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Always
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: WithoutElse
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: Empty
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
AlignConsecutiveShortCaseStatements:
  Enabled: true
  AcrossEmptyLines: false
  AcrossComments: false
  AlignCaseColons: false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: true
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: true
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: false
  BeforeWhile: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
  IndentBraces: false
BracedInitializerIndentWidth: 4
BreakAfterAttributes: Never
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: NonAssignment
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: Always
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit: 160
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
EmptyLineAfterAccessModifier: Never
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always
FixNamespaceComments: true
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IndentAccessModifiers: false
IndentCaseBlocks: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentExternBlock: Indent
IndentGotoLabels: false
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash
IndentRequiresClause: false
IndentWidth: 4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
InsertBraces: true
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
InsertTrailingCommas: Wrapped
KeepEmptyLinesAtEOF: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
LambdaBodyIndentation: Signature
LineEnding: DeriveCRLF
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
PackConstructorInitializers: CurrentLine
ReferenceAlignment: Left
ReflowComments: false
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RemoveParentheses: ReturnStatement
RemoveSemicolon: false
RequiresClausePosition: OwnLine
RequiresExpressionIndentation: OuterScope
SeparateDefinitionBlocks: Always
ShortNamespaceLines: 0
SortIncludes: CaseInsensitive
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SortUsingDeclarations: Lexicographic
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: Default
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: false
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterIfMacros: true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: true
  AfterRequiresInClause: true
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
  AfterRequiresInExpression: true
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: Never
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInLineCommentPrefix:
  Minimum: 1
  Maximum: 1
SpacesInParens: Never
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
PointerAlignment: Left
QualifierAlignment: Left

The .clang-format file is used to automatically format files on a github workflow, but i've failed to get clang-format running on v18, so i'm trying to get it to work on v17. How can i prevent the std::cout line from breaking on clang-format v17?

a hint: CommentPragmas:  'std::cout'?
CommentPragmas is expected a regular expression that tells clang-format. I'm not sure exactly how to use it in your case, so you'll have to experiment by yourself (I used it myself to exclude doxygen comments from formatting)

CommentPragmas would require me to place a comment that matches the regex so that the line is ignored. But I don't want to place a comment to prevent the line from formatting. imo, it would then be better to turn clang-format off and back on for that line

I don't think so. In my .clang-format I've got "CommentPragmas:  '^\.+'" that excludes lines containing '' followed by one or more character (if my regexp is not too wrong). Btw, the correct regexp might be '^std::cout' according to a test I just made in clang-format configurator
